# count observations by group based on conditions of 2 variables in R

Tags: r, group-by, count, dplyr

This is the shor example data. Original data has many columns and rows.

head(df, 15)

```
    ID   col1   col2
1   1  green yellow
2   1  green   blue
3   1  green  green
4   2 yellow   blue
5   2 yellow yellow
6   2 yellow   blue
7   3 yellow yellow
8   3 yellow yellow
9   3 yellow   blue
10  4   blue yellow
11  4   blue yellow
12  4   blue yellow
13  5 yellow yellow
14  5 yellow   blue
15  5 yellow yellow
```

what I want to count how many different colors in col2 including the color of col1. For ex: for the ID=4, there is only 1 color in col2. if we include col1, there are 2 different colors. So output should be 2 and so on.

I tried in this way, but it doesn't give me my desired output: ID = 4  turns into 0 which is not I want. So how could I tell R to count them including color in col1?

```
out <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(N = ifelse(col1 != col2, 1, 0))
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
ID  col1    count
1   green   3
2   yellow  2
3   yellow  2
4   blue    2
5   yellow  2
```

Comment: Note that the df you display is not equal to the df you `dput`. In particular, the displayed df only has one unique value of `col2` when `ID == 4` and `col1 == "blue"`

Comment: Sorry I changed it a bit to make my point be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID, col1) %>%
 summarise(count = n_distinct(col2))

     ID col1   count
  <int> <chr>  <int>
1     1 green      3
2     2 yellow     2
3     3 yellow     2
4     4 blue       1
5     5 yellow     2
```

Or even:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID, col1) %>%
 summarise_all(n_distinct)

     ID col1    col2
  <int> <chr>  <int>
1     1 green      3
2     2 yellow     2
3     3 yellow     2
4     4 blue       1
5     5 yellow     2
```

To group by every three rows:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group = gl(n()/3, 3), col1) %>%
 summarise(count = n_distinct(col2))
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It works but my original data has 600 rows after grouping by 3 rows, the length of the output should be 200. but it is 199 rows. can we fix it?

Comment: I found the reason of it. There is a replicated code. can I ask if I want to count it 3 by 3 rows how can I change the code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "3 by 3 rows"?

Comment: I mean that ID and col1 can be grouped by every 3 rows. I want to count the number  of different observations for each 3 rows (i.e. count for 1-3, 4-6, etc) and extract the same dataframe. Is it possible or not?